# python read .csv file - access list elements in a field

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file with "|" as separator in this format (one line sample):

```
01|a|b|c|(d,e,[(f,g,h)])
```

I have to convert it into a new .csv file keeping only some element from the last field as:

```
01|a|b|c|f|g
```

So far I tried reading it line by line with:

```
# Set Workbooks for .csv
f = open('output.csv', 'wt')

writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')

writer.writerow( 
                (
                'f1',
                'f2',
                'f3',
                'f4',
                'f5',
                'f6'
                )

with open('input.csv', 'r') as csvfile:

    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')

    for row in spamreader:

        writer.writerow(
                        (
                        row[0],
                        row[1],
                        row[2],
                        row[3],
                        row[4][2][0][1],
                        row[4][2][0][2]
                        )
                        )

f.close()
```

So try to parse the list elements of the last field of the `input.csv` file, but it returns a:

```
row[4][2][0][1], IndexError: string index out of range
```

So actually it is not possible to access the tuple. Is there a way to do this? I would use `pandas` to do this, but the file is too big so I need to read it line by line.

Comment: Your `row[5]` should be `row[4]` becouse the tuple is int he 5th element with  is in index 4, also are you sure you can access it like this? row[x] will return a string....

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, I've corrected the index. I know the it returns a string, that's why I asked whether there is a method to access those nested elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is going to be a very hacky way to go about it.
But if your format stays the same, you could try doing:

```
row = [[01],["a"],["b"],["c"],["(d,e,[(f,g,h)])"]]
string = str(row) # "01|a|b|c|(d,e,[(f,g,h)])"
a = string.split('|')[:-1]
b = string.split('|')[-1].split('(')[2:][0].split(',')[:2]
result = a + b
print result
```

> result: ['01', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g']

Then you could use csv writer to write the list with: `writer.writerow(result)`

Answer (score 2):

With the code I see there, row would be:

['01', 'a', 'b', '(d,e,[(f,g,h)])']

So the last element is a string, not a tuple with a list inside, etc. so you would have to parse this string.

Comment: There's no way to convert that string into a tuple?

Comment: I don't think so, because that is not valid python. If it was valid python you could do an eval() (I wouldn't recommend it), and if it was a valid json you could do json.loads(). Here I think you better get what you want with a regular expression.